# elasticsearch must_not clause specifically does not work with empty string "" as value

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Basically as the title states. I have confirmed must_not does work if i am specifying a string with some non empty string as what the field must not match. This works:

```
query=dict(
   bool=dict(
        must_not=dict(
            term=dict(
               {"platform_base": "cats"}
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

If instead though I want to exclude all the entries with the platform_base set to be an empty string "" like so:

```
actual_query = dict(
     query=dict(
         bool=dict(
             must_not=dict(
                  term=dict(
                       {"platform_base": ""}
                  ),
             ),
         ),
     ),
 )
```

suddenly it doesnt work and the must_not filter is not applied and entries are returned that have platform_base set to "". Is this expected behavior? How can I get the results I desire?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
   "query" : {
       "regexp":{
           "<your_field_name_here>": ".+"
        }
    }
}
```

this got it